# Trimmed a video with ffmpeg; looks fine on a Mac, but audio/video are 3 seconds out of sync with Windows default player. Huh?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've got a video which looks and sounds right when I play it in Windows or on a Mac.
I trimmed it with ffmpeg.
The resulting file

- plays fine on a Mac with QuickTime
- throws an error on Windows QuickTime (Error -2041: an invalid sample description was found in the movie (myfile.trimmed.mp4))
- plays with Win10's default player (Movies and TV?), but with the audio lagging nearly 3 seconds behind the video (as determined by me counting Mississippis, nothing more precise than that.)

My original file:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner myfile.mpg
[h264 @ 00000253d2d762c0] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
[mpegts @ 00000253d2d6fe00] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 00000253d2d6fe00] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 8467425232).
[mpegts @ 00000253d2d6fe00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none ([151][0][0][0] / 0x0097)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'myfile.mpg':
  Duration: 00:30:00.63, start: 92282.982578, bitrate: 6249 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1aab]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1abf]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1ac1]: Unknown: none ([151][0][0][0] / 0x0097)
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

Stuff I notice:

- The mpg container shouldn't hold h264 video.  That messed me up, but remuxing to an mp4 container during the trimming step seemed to make it OK.
- The start time isn't anywhere close to zero...  but I don't think there's anything wrong with that.
- The audio and video are in sync as I watch in a player, but the file contains audio starting nearly 1 second before the video.  The first audio packet has pkt_pts_time=92282.982578 (matching the start reported by ffprobe, above), while the first video packet has pkt_pts_time=92283.926411

So I trim it, like so...

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss 00:17:24 -i myfile.mpg -t 00:02:40 -c copy myfile.trimmed.mp4
[h264 @ 000002d5d73f4040] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
[mpegts @ 000002d5d73edbc0] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 000002d5d73edbc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 8467425232).
[mpegts @ 000002d5d73edbc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none ([151][0][0][0] / 0x0097)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000002d5d73edbc0] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 000002d5d73edbc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 8467425232).
Input #0, mpegts, from 'myfile.mpg':
  Duration: 00:30:00.63, start: 92282.982578, bitrate: 6249 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1aab]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1abf]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1ac1]: Unknown: none ([151][0][0][0] / 0x0097)
[mp4 @ 000002d5d7e90540] track 1: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, mp4, to 'myfile.trimmed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 9570 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  122587kB time=00:02:39.99 bitrate=6276.6kbits/s speed= 462x
video:114772kB audio:7545kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.220873%
```

```
ffprobe -hide_banner myfile.trimmed.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'myfile.trimmed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:02:40.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6239 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 5890 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
```

...and i get the file that plays fine on a Mac, but not on Windows's default player.
The start time as reported by ffprobe is 0 (above), so that must've been cleaned up by either the trimming or the remuxing.  When I look at frames, the first audio packet has a pkt_pts_time=0.000000, and the first video packet has a pkt_pts_time=0.452000.

Where do I go next?

Comment: Could you try not copying the video stream? Not that this is somehow an keyframe placement issue.

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss 00:17:24 -i myfile.mpg -t 00:02:40 -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 23 myfile.trimmed.mp4`

Comment: Show the complete log **without** `-hide_banner`.

Comment: I noticed FFmpeg is warning the DTS (Decoding Time Stamp) is invalid for stream 1. As you previously mentioned this H.264 file came from TivoDecode, so some dregs of an MPEG-TS structure may still be present, including original DTS and PTS. Your file may start with a non-keyframe as well.     I'd try a `ffmpeg -fflags +genpts` before the source mpg and doing a copy remux. If that doesn't work, try copying the streams from the .mpg to a .ts file, run that through TS-Doctor and see if it can fix the PES issue. See also splitting to m4v and m4a and remuxing with FFmpeg's `itsoffset` feature.

Comment: Nothing's worked.  Not copying the video stream didn't help; still see the multi-second gap between audio and video under Windows.  TS_Doctor didn't help; I still get complaints about "PES packet size mismatch" and "Packet corrupt" on the fixed TS file.  (It's not clear to me whether TS_Doctor thinks it fixed everything, or if it simply noted that yep, I've got 7 errors.)  I also tried switching to tivodecode_ng for the original .tivo to (incorrect) .mpg first step, and that made no difference.  And the Mac still seems able to play all the files I generate, with the audio and video sync'ed.